# What is the best practice for managing subscriptions in RxScala?

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I want to control the scope for my subscriptions and even in the presence of exceptions while avoiding using **var** for my subscriptions

In Rx/F# I would do this

```
use subscription = Observable.subscribe ...
```

and the subscription is automatically disposed when leaving the scope.

What is the best practice in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use [scala-arm](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm) but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

I added an implicit conversion from Subscription to Resource and used managed resource mechanism from scala-arm like this:

```
object ResourceImplicits {
  implicit val subscription2Resource = new Resource[Subscription] {
    override def close(s: Subscription): Unit = s.unsubscribe()  }
}

//...

for (s <- managed(obs.subscribe { n => println(s"n=$n")})) {
    // the subscription is alive in this scope
    // ...
}
//the subscription has been unsubscribed
```